# how to know when css3 animation ends

Tags: css

How do I change or remove a css class from a html object, when the animation ends? I would like to remove a div when the animation ends...

```
.loginAnimado
{        
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#F2F2F2;
    position:relative;            
    -webkit-animation:mymove 1s 1; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove /* Safari and Chrome */
{
    from 
    {                       
    }

    to 
    {        
        opacity: 0.0;    
        -webkit-transform: scale(2) rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(0deg, 0deg);               
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need Javascript for this, it's easier with jQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.loginAnimado').bind("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd animationEnd", function(){
     $(this).removeClass('loginAnimado');
  });  
});
```

Answer (score 7):

The animationend events *are* case sensitive, and vary from browser to browser. The official spec is all lowercase, though the various browser prefixes even vary in their implementation too.

```
Mozilla: mozAnimationEnd
Webkit: webkitAnimationEnd
Opera: oanimationend
IE: MSAnimationEnd
W3C: animationend
```

See this jsfiddle for a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/xTxBe/).

Comment: Thanks, this is a great example. Curiously - if annoyingly - IE 11 seems to only heed animationend.

Comment: In fact animationEnd doesn't work in a timely fashion in IE11 either: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/1605631/animation-end-events-firing-late

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer currently fires twice for animations in Chrome (it also uses `.bind` when the preferred method since jQuery 1.7 is now `.on`).  Presumably this is because it recognizes `webkitAnimationEnd` as well as `animationEnd`. The following will definitely only fires once:

```
/* From Modernizr */
function whichTransitionEvent(){

    var el = document.createElement('fakeelement');
    var transitions = {
        'animation':'animationend',
        'OAnimation':'oAnimationEnd',
        'MSAnimation':'MSAnimationEnd',
        'WebkitAnimation':'webkitAnimationEnd'
    };

    for(var t in transitions){
        if( transitions.hasOwnProperty(t) && el.style[t] !== undefined ){
            return transitions[t];
        }
    }
}

$("#elementToListenTo")
    .on(whichTransitionEvent(),
        function(e){
            // What you want to do here
            $('.loginAnimado').removeClass('loginAnimado');
            $(this).off(e);
        });
```